# Get inferred type arguments from TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have the following type and function signature

```
type Ctor<T> = {
  new (): T
}

export function foo<T>(Ctor: Ctor<T>) {

}

class Bar { foo = 'what' }

foo(Bar) // inferred type of T is Bar
```

I trying to get the inferred type of T at the call site `foo(Bar)` using the compiler api. So far I've tried,

```
if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) { 
  const funcType = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node.expression)
}
```

But this only gets the declared type of `foo`. It doesn't have the type arguments passed to it at the call site. I've also tried,

```
if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) { 
  const args = node.typeArguments
}
```

But this is also empty, I think because the types are not explicitly passed.

So how do I get the inferred type of T at each call site?

Comment: The question is not clear: the inferred type of `T` is the type of the argument you're passing to the function, so you already know it. Can you show a full minimal example of what you've tried, and what you'd like to get?

Comment: It's not the type of the argument, in this example, type of the argument is `typeof Bar` but T is type `Bar`. So I cant directly get `T` by checking the type of the argument.

Comment: @Blackhole OP is trying to get the inferred type of the `foo` call (which should be `foo<Bar>(Bar)`) through the compiler API. The two attempts they have shown aren't successful.

Comment: I just added the "typescript-compiler-api" tag, to better categorize the question and, I hope, to make it more obvious that this isn't just a regular typescript question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information from the resolved signature:

```
if (ts.isCallExpression(node)) {
  const signature = checker.getResolvedSignature(node);
  if (signature != null) {
    // outputs -- (Ctor: Ctor<Bar>): void
    console.log(checker.signatureToString(signature));
    const params = signature.getParameters();
    for (const param of params) {
      const type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(param, node);
      // outputs -- Ctor<Bar>
      console.log(checker.typeToString(type));
    }
  }
}
```